# Writing tabular data to a csv file from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to parse some data from a webpage and write it to a csv file via panda. So far what I've written can parse all the tables available in that page but in case of writing to a csv file it is writing the last table from that page to that csv file. Definitely, the data are being overwritten because of the loop. How can I fix this flaw so that my scraper will be able to write all the data from different tables instead of only the last table? Thanks in advance.

```
import csv
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


res = requests.get('http://www.espn.com/nba/schedule/_/date/20171001').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
for table in soup.find_all("table"):
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    df.to_csv("table_item.csv")
    print(df)
```

Btw, I expect to write data to a csv file using panda only. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) what return `list of DataFrames` in webpage, so then need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for one `df`:

```
dfs = pd.read_html('http://www.espn.com/nba/schedule/_/date/20171001')

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
#if necessary rename columns
d = {'Unnamed: 1':'a', 'Unnamed: 7':'b'}
df = df.rename(columns=d)
print (df.head())
               matchup               a  time (ET)  nat tv  away tv  home tv  \
0          Atlanta ATL       Miami MIA        NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN   
1               LA LAC     Toronto TOR        NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN   
2  Guangzhou Guangzhou  Washington WSH        NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN   
3        Charlotte CHA      Boston BOS        NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN   
4          Orlando ORL     Memphis MEM        NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN   

                           tickets   b  
0  2,401 tickets available from $6 NaN  
1   284 tickets available from $29 NaN  
2  2,792 tickets available from $2 NaN  
3  2,908 tickets available from $6 NaN  
4  1,508 tickets available from $3 NaN
```

And last [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for write to file:

```
df.to_csv("table_item.csv", index=False)
```

EDIT:

For learning is possible append each `DataFrame` to list and then `concat`:

```
res = requests.get('http://www.espn.com/nba/schedule/_/date/20171001').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
dfs = []
for table in soup.find_all("table"):
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print(df)

df.to_csv("table_item.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, for such an elaborative answer and the clarity. It serves the purpose. However, for the learning purpose: could you please suggest me how could i write those data to a csv file if i wanted to stick to the way I started in my post.

Comment: Glad can help ;) Good luck!